# Don't break words at whitespace with CSS

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a div with a set width. The way text is broken by default is at a white space. Is there any way to set the style of my element, so that the text is broken at any given character to fill out the maximum space available?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: As an aside there are jQuery hyphenation plugins that would do "this" for you (Not exactly what you ask, but maybe even nicer)

Comment: Hi! have you tried { word-wrap: break-word; }

?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, I am not using jQuery on this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word-break property in CSS can be used to change when line breaks ought to occur. Normally, line breaks in text can only occur in certain spaces, like when there is a space or a hyphen. But using `word-break: break-all` we can override that.

As an aside this can be very useful for stopping long urls from breaking out of text containers.

```css
div {
 width: 200px;
 background: pink;
}
    
p {word-break: break-all; }
```

```html
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery "alternative"**

Plugins including, but not limited to,  https://github.com/bramstein/hypher can also be employed and will likely give a nicer overall appearance by using associated dictionaries (language dependent) to hyphenate the words properly when they break.